# Apache configuration. Apache access.log showing 404 for every subpage

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to set project locally for development that works in production in my job. Almost every page throw 404 f.e http://localhost/project1/producers/wear.html . It happends on Ubuntu and Windows.

My project locally sit under var/www/html/project1 and is visible under http://localhost/project1/ , in job it is visible under http://project1/

log/apache2/access.log showing 404:

```
127.0.0.1 (..)"GET /project1/shop/clothing.html (..)" 404 17601 "http://localhost/project1/"(..)
127.0.0.1 (..)"GET /public/css/font-awesome.min.css (..)" 404 521 "http://localhost/project1/shop/clothing.html"(..)
127.0.0.1 (..)"GET /public/css/bootstrap.min.css (..)" 404 518 "http://localhost/project1/shop/clothing.html"(..)
127.0.0.1 (..)"GET /public/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js (..)" 404 518 "http://localhost/project1/shop/clothing.html"(..)
127.0.0.1 (..)"GET /public/js/bootstrap.min.js (..)" 404 515 "http://localhost/project1/shop/clothing.html"(..)
127.0.0.1 (..)"GET /public/js/base/frontend.js (..)" 404 515 "http://localhost/project1/shop/clothing.html"(..)
127.0.0.1 (..)"GET /files/graphics/logo.png (..)" 404 512 "http://localhost/project1/shop/clothing.html"(..)
```

apache2.conf:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

project1/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```

project1/public/.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine off
```

project1/upload/.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine off
```

project1/system/.htaccess:

```
deny from all
```

project1/application/.htaccess (controllers, entities):

```
deny from all
```

also HTML style src are f.e.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

---

edit:

after putting in var/www/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I have access to styles, js files from in project1/public/:

```
127.0.0.1 "GET /project1/shop/supplements.html" 404 17608 "http://localhost/project1/new.html" 
127.0.0.1 "GET /public/css/bootstrap.min.css" 301 626 "http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html" 
127.0.0.1 "GET /public/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" 301 627 "http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html"
127.0.0.1 "GET /project1/public/css/font-awesome.min.css" 200 6580 "http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html"
127.0.0.1 "GET /project1/public/css/flag-icon.min.css" 200 3113 "http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html" 
127.0.0.1 "GET /project1/public/css/ilightbox.css" 200 1848 "http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html" 
127.0.0.1 "GET /public/js/base/frontend.js" 301 621 "http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html"
127.0.0.1 "GET /project1/public/js/jquery.requestAnimationFrame.js" 200 1001 "http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html" 
127.0.0.1 "GET /files/graphics/logo.png" 301 615 "http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html"
127.0.0.1 "GET /project1/public/js/base/frontend.js" 200 1195 "http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html" 
127.0.0.1 "GET /project1/public/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=1.7.22" 304 182 "http://localhost/project1/public/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
::1 - - [11/Jun/2017:11:51:01 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g (internal dummy connection)"
```

but still every site in project is 404, f.e. `http://localhost/project1/bestsellers.html` log in access.log

```
127.0.0.1 "GET /project1/bestsellers.html HTTP/1.1" 404 17608 "http://localhost/project1/recommended.html"
```

and every page throws `Uups... Page not found!` but with a STYLE! at least:)

Comment: Your root directory looks to be `/var/www/` rather than `/var/www/html/` based on the config provided.

Comment: so I need to change `<Directory /var/www/>` to `<Directory /var/www/html>` in apache2.conf? I did, it not helping me. Or You mean to move my project to /var/www/ and create virtual host to access `http:/project1/` rather than `http:/localhost/project1/ `?

Comment: No, I think your app is using that as the base directory, so your app is actually at `localhost/html`, does this work: http://localhost/html/project1/public/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: no, `The requested URL /html/projects1/public/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js was not found on this server.`

Comment: Is this file `/project1/shop/clothing.html` located at `/var/www/html/project1/shop/clothing.html`? If so can you show the output of `ls -lR /var/www/html/project1` in your question?

Comment: no, clothing.html is not located in /shop/ (Anyway i made ls -lR,it is huge. Put it in txt file here ufile.io/htb7e. Looking for shared text file service with no restrictions)

Comment: clothing.html doesn't exist in that dir listing but is in your error log as the source which was access but has missing files. The /public/ directory needs to be on the same level /shop/ to work, wherever you have ./shop/, the rest of the directories there and it'll work.

Comment: there is no clothing.html file at all in project. Its just part of naming route convention this project has.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that you're rewriting to `/project1/index.php`, the folder 'public' is inside this folder making it accessible at `/project1/public/...` however you're attempting to access `/public/...` which is a directory above your project.

Comment: yes in browser developer tools I can see while opening `http://localhost/project1/shop/supplements.html` there are 404 attempts to f.e. `http://localhost/public/css/bootstrap.min.css` instead of `http://localhost/project1/public/css/bootstrap.min.css` . So what is responsible for this?

Comment: Your HTML is likely using absolute links, I know the example you posted is relative however it's usually run from a root domain so there might be something in your application which is expecting it to be a root domain rather than a subfolder.

Comment: yes, I can agree. So I need to create virtual host and make project available at `http://project1/` instead of `http://localhost/project1/`. Right?

Comment: I've added an answer that should allow you to fix it now I have an understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your app isn't designed to run within a subfolder, if this is the only project you're running you could add a .htaccess to redirect back to the projects folder, put this in `/var/www/html`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Alternatively you could look for specific directories only

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /project1/public/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: We almost done! Style and js files are used now but every site in project is 404. Check my edit part in main post. (Thanks for what You have done so far!)

Comment: If you change the rewrite in project1/.htaccess to `/index.php` (or maybe `/project1/index.php`) rather than `index.php` it should fix the problem

Comment: No, same result.

Comment: Just please tell me if this should work if all project htaccess files remain original and i will create virtual host and make project available at `http://project1/` instead of `http://localhost/project1/` and place files in `var/www/` instead od `var/www/html`

Comment: Is the page not found page you’re seeing from your application?  If so it’s because it doesn’t expect the /project1/ subdirectory.

Comment: Yeah it should work fine if you move it to a root level with its own vhost. The errors you’re seeing now seem application related due to the additional subdirectory

Comment: thanks for Your effort. I will accept you answer later anyway.